# Django 2.0 Notifications: How to overwrite the default list.html page for django-notifications

Tags: django, django-notification

So, I recently imported [Django-notifications](https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications) and have successfully added a notification or two. Now I want to look at the list page. In my urls I have added the notification endpoint `path('notifications/', include("notifications.urls")),` and when I go to the url, I get [the output that matches the documentation](https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications/blob/master/notifications/templates/notifications/notice.html):

Now, How do I go about changing the notification url. I tried to create an app for notifications `python manage.py startapp notifications`, but it said that one already existed. I feel like I'm missing something simple, but I can't put a finger on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create your own app, `notifications`, because you already have an installed app called `notifications`.  This is the app you downloaded/installed and  added to `your_project/settings.py` under `INSTALLED_APPS`

To view the default list, you can `python manage.py runserver`, and navigate to `localhost:8000/notifications/' to see the default`list.html`.

From there, I recommend creating your own list.  Looking at the documentation [here](https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications#API), you'll find all the QuerySet methods.  You can build a view based on these queries. e.g. `your-app/views.py`:

```
...

# Get all unread notifications for current user.
def unread_notifications(request):
    context = {
        'notifications': request.user.notifications.unread()
    }

    return render(request, 'your-app/unread_notifications.html', context)
```

And your `your-app/unread_notifications.html` (assuming bootstrap):

```
<ul class="notifications">
    {% for notice in notifications %}
    <div class="alert alert-block alert-{{ notice.level }}">
        <a class="close pull-right" href="{% url 'notifications:mark_as_read' notice.slug %}">
            <i class="icon-close"></i>
        </a>

        <h4>
            <i class="icon-mail{% if notice.unread %}-alt{% endif %}"></i>
            {{ notice.actor }}
            {{ notice.verb }}
            {% if notice.target %}
            of {{ notice.target }}
            {% endif %}
        </h4>

        <p>{{ notice.timesince }} ago</p>

        <p>{{ notice.description|linebreaksbr }}</p>

        <div class="notice-actions">
            {% for action in notice.data.actions %}
            <a class="btn" href="{{ action.href }}">{{ action.title }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```